# C# LINQ Group By and run method on that group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that is looking at the results of a method that compares a source file to target files, and returns custom objects where a property from the source file is different in any of the target files:

```
var conflictsAndSources = from conflict in FileConflicts
                                      from source in SourceFileObjects
                                      where conflict.Name == source.Name && conflict.PropertyA != source.PropertyA
                                      select new { Conflict = conflict, Source = source };
```

From this query I am getting a collection `conflictsAndSources` that I feed into the following method:

```
foreach (var conflictAndSource in conflictsAndSources)
                access.FixFileConflict(conflictAndSource.Conflict.FilePath, conflictAndSource.Conflict.Name, conflictAndSource.Source.PropertyA);
```

The method works, but a problem arises in my FixFileConflict method. Every time this method runs in the foreach loop the file has to be opened, modified, saved, and closed. The problem is there could be hundreds of conflicts all for the same file, so the file will be opened and modified hundreds of times. I obviously want to find a way to group those conflicts by FilePath and pass them all into the method.

I'm getting stuck on that part. So far I have this...

```
            var Groups = conflictsAndSources.GroupBy(x => (x.Conflict.FilePath));

            foreach(var group in Groups)
            {
                da.FixGroupOfFileConflicts(group.Key, the rest of the owl);
            }
```

I don't need help on the `FixGroupOfFileConflicts` method, but how to pass into that method the whole group to be processed.

For every File, there are layers, and each layer has a several properties. In this method I am looking to open up the file which I think will be `group.Key`, and then every item in that group has a `.Name` and a `PropertyA` setting. I need to pass every member of the group into `FixGroupOfFileConflicts` so I can open the file, then iterate through the group that was passed in to it to find every layer and set it's PropertyA to Source.PropertyA accordingly.

Comment: Can you share the code for items in `FileConflicts` collection? And `FixFileConflict` method

Comment: `group.ToList()` or `group.ToArray()` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the easiest way:

```
    var Groups = conflictsAndSources.GroupBy(x => x.Conflict.FilePath, x => x.Source);

    foreach(var group in Groups)        
    {
         da.FixGroupOfFileConflicts(group.Key, group);
    }
```

Then the FixGroupOfFileConflicts method signature would be this:

```
FixGroupOfFileConflicts(string conflictFilePath, IEnumerable<source type here> conflictsOfTheFile);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I was wondering if you could explain a little bit what the second part of the GroupBy is doing, with the x=>x.Source part.

Comment: The second lambda in GroupBy collects the objects of the group. Without it GroupBy would return groups of anonymous objects that would be less convenient to access. I do not even know what exactly IEnumerable<> parameter would be then. IEnumerable<object> maybe? Accessing the field of anonymous type from object reference does not look fun to me. I could be wrong though but by adding x -> x.Source I can make sure that I will get known type.